# How long does it take to extract a tree core for dendrochronological analysis

Tags: ecology, trees, dendrology

I'm going to do research in the tropics and am considering using tree cores for part of my analysis. However, for my planning:

How long does it take on average to extract a tree core of a tree with dbh ~50 cm? Trees will vary in wood density between 0.2 and 0.8.

The time includes labelling and storing in a bag, etc.

Tools: increment haglof borer. So I won't take a whole cross section, rather a small core of ~5 mm diameter that goes until the core.

And no picture because I need a more high quality image to be able to do my analysis.

Comment: Extract the core?  What do you mean?  Do you mean cut a cross-section?  In any case, it will very much depend what tools you have, how fast you work, etc.

Comment: You want to store cross section of 50cm tree cross-section in a bag? Can't you just take pictures?

Comment: Oh I guess you're planning to drill a sample through the trunk, are you?

Comment: Exactly, that is the plan.

Comment: Given the assumption that you know how to properly core (i.e., you've done this before): taking into account fatigue, bark abnormalities, post-processing and storage, and walking between nearby trees, I'd guess you'd average 5-10 every hour across the course of a full day.